# Spring MVC installation

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I would like to create instalation process for the first run of my Spring MVC app. Something like   wordpress has (when you first run it, you need to specify DB connection and your first admin account... etc.

I have tried it with spring but the spring won't start because when DataSource Bean is not connected, it will simply fail to start. It always fail when transaction manager bean is beeing created:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in SpringWebConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sessionFactory' is required|#]
```

Is there any way how to start the spring/hibernate app without transaction manager and then load it on-the-fly when user configures his db access details ? I know there is way to do it with application.properties but I want to create a simple install process just like in wordpress so it is most convenient for non-tech users.

EDIT 1: My current code:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"test"}) //package scan
public class SpringWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public BasicDataSource dataSource() {
    if (Config.getInstance().isInstalled()) {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://" + Config.getInstance().getDburl() + "/" + Config.getInstance().getDbname());
        ds.setUsername(Config.getInstance().getDbuser());
        ds.setPassword(Config.getInstance().getDbpass());
        this.ds = ds;
    }
    return ds;
}

@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager txManager() {
    if (sessionFactory() == null) {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager();
    }
    else return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
}

@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    try {
        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource());
        builder.scanPackages(dbEntity).addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        return builder.buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Did you try @Lazy on the bean? Not sure if it'll work... just a first thought. If that doesn't work, my second thought might be to create the bean on the fly at start up instead of hard coding it.

Comment: I have added my current spring config code

Comment: if you wanna follow the wordpress logic then you should first get the info of connection, app name, etc and at the end of all of it then start the app, like this you won't have a problem, if you start the app without specifying the database and later update the properties it won't auto-refresh, you will need to restart the app

Answer (score 0):

Adding @Lazy to all 3 @Beans solves the issue and hibernate is not requiered at the startup of Spring MVC (configured by class that implements WebMvcConfigurer), this allows to display install page for the user so he can define DB access details.